# Android SDK option is disabled

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015

Android SDK Option is disable in Visual studio 2015.
Find the attached image screenshots[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyFKI.png)

Comment: have to uninstall Visual Studio 2015, download the latest version and reinstall

Comment: I found the same solution ...Is there any other way to troubleshoot it...

Comment: I fear there would be no solution other than this

Comment: hmmm....BTW Thanks for your reply Avinash :)

Comment: Happy coding nitu :)

Comment: ohh....thanks ...same to u